# Remove plural suffix from a word in java

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I want to replace words such as 'monsters' by 'monster' , 'crashes' by 'crash'. How do i write regular expression?

Comment: You won't be able to do that with a regex. What would you do for `places`? replace it by `place` or by `plac`?

Comment: Not easy, how to detect the difference between crashes/crash and caches/cache? Not to speak about children/child.

Comment: ... and all those that are even more irregular, e.g. sheep, mice, geese, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`String.replaceAll(regex, charSeq)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)**

```
String str="monsters";
str = str.replaceAll("\\w$","");
System.out.println(str);
```

1. $   Checks if a line end follows
2. \w  A word character, short for [a-zA-Z_0-9]

If you only want to change the words which has character `s` at the end.

```
str = str.replaceAll("s$","");
```

Comment: Thanks..this is working for given cases. I will think about how to apply it to more general cases which are mentioned in comments above.